ts-jest not configured to match tsc options
I started a new typescript project using this boilerplate: https://github.com/jsynowiec/node-typescript-boilerplate
Some code works fine via npm run build && npm start but not by npm test.
Setup code
git clone https://github.com/jsynowiec/node-typescript-boilerplate.git
cd node-typescript-boilerplate
npm install

Then added to bottom of main.ts
console.log(await greeter('Bob'));

Then run:
npm run build && npm start
npm test

Notice how start works fine, but test outputs this error:
 FAIL  __tests__/main.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run
    src/main.ts:36:13 - error TS1378: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', 'nodenext', or 'preserve', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.
    console.log(await greeter('Bob'));

Swap the lines to the bottom of main.ts
import path from 'path';
async function init() {
  console.log(path.basename('test/path/filename.json'));
  console.log(await greeter('Bob'));
}
init();

Then run:
npm run build && npm start
npm test

Notice how start works fine, but test outputs this error:
 RUNS  __tests__/main.test.ts
/node-typescript-boilerplate/src/main.ts:497
  console.log(path_1.default.basename('test/path/filename.json'));
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'basename')

Why does this code run fine via start and not via test?
My suspicion is that ts-jest is not configured to work in the same way as tsconfig.
But I cannot figure out the correct configuration to make them compatible with each other.
I've opened an issue with boilerplate repo author here too:
https://github.com/jsynowiec/node-typescript-boilerplate/issues/59

Fixed node module imports by adding this line to tsconfig.json:
"esModuleInterop": true

For the top-level async await you need a special combination of configuration using:

https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/
https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

Or switch from ts-jest to vitest which is built to be ESM first with top level await:
https://vitest.dev/guide/features.html
